# Как расположить иконку рядом с текстом

Tags: html, css

Создал меню на основе грид.
Попытался вставить иконку рядом со ссылкой, но сам текст ссылки уехал вверх.
Как сделать, чтобы иконка нормально стояла рядом с текстом ссылки.

**Как достичь результата как на картинке внизу?**

[image: Как достичь такого результата?]

```css
body {
  font-size: 17px;
  word-break: break-all;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(10%, 20%));
  grid-template-areas: "Menu Menu Menu Menu Menu";
}

.Main_Menu {
  grid-area: Menu;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 0.5vw;
  background: gray;
}

nav ul li {
  margin-left: 1vw;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 75px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

nav ul li a {
  font-family: 'Arial';
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.2vw;
  color: orange;
}

.home_icon {
  width: 2vw;
  margin-left: -3vw;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <nav class="Main_Menu">

    <ul>

      <li> <a href="/">1</a>
        <img class="home_icon" src="https://i.ibb.co/nRhPGzp/1-home.png">
      </li>

      <li> <a href="/">2</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="/">3</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="/">4</a> </li>
      <li> <a href="/">5</a> </li>

    </ul>

  </nav>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ничто не мешает использовать *flex* совместно с *grid*, так почему бы этим не воспользоваться? А вот злоупотребление внешними/внутренними отступами - плохая практика.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 15px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(10%, 20%));
  grid-template-areas: "Menu Menu Menu Menu Menu";
  font-size: 17px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.Main_Menu {
  grid-area: Menu;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 2vw;
  gap: 4vw;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #000;
  background: gray;
}

nav ul li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 0.5vw;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #000;
}

nav ul li a {
  font: 1.5vw "Arial";
  text-decoration: none;
  color: orange;
}

.home_icon {
  width: 2vw;
}
```

```html
<nav class="Main_Menu">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/">1 пункт</a>
      <img class="home_icon" src="https://i.ibb.co/nRhPGzp/1-home.png">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/">2 пункт</a>
      <img class="home_icon" src="https://i.ibb.co/nRhPGzp/1-home.png">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/">3 пункт</a>
      <img class="home_icon" src="https://i.ibb.co/nRhPGzp/1-home.png">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/">4 пункт</a>
      <img class="home_icon" src="https://i.ibb.co/nRhPGzp/1-home.png">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/">5 пункт</a>
      <img class="home_icon" src="https://i.ibb.co/nRhPGzp/1-home.png">
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133741/discussion-on-answer-by-umodel------).